# SCons: GCC Ignoring -c

Tags: command-line, gcc, arguments, scons

I'm using a MinGW-based GCC cross-compiler to compile a project which uses SCons as its build system.

The Python is a native 2.6.2 version, not specifically compiled for MinGW (or Cygwin).

However, I am running into a problem with the build:

```
F:/pedigree/compilers/bin/i686-elf-gcc -o build\src\user\applications\apptest\ma
in.obj -c -std=gnu99 -march=i486 -fno-builtin -m32 -g0 -O3 -Wno-long-long -Wnest
ed-externs -Wall -Wextra -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-
long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-conversion -Wno-
format -Wno-empty-body -fno-stack-protector -DTHREADS -DDEBUGGER -DDEBUGGER_QWER
TY -DSERIAL_IS_FILE -DECHO_CONSOLE_TO_SERIAL -DKERNEL_NEEDS_ADDRESS_SPACE_SWITCH
 -DADDITIONAL_CHECKS -DBITS_32 -DKERNEL_STANDALONE -DVERBOSE_LINKER -DX86 -DX86_
COMMON -DLITTLE_ENDIAN -D__UD_STANDALONE__ -DINSTALLER -Isrc\subsys\posix\includ
e -Ibuild\src\user\applications\apptest -Isrc\user\applications\apptest src\user
\applications\apptest\main.c
f:/pedigree/compilers/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-elf/4.4.1/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld.
exe: crt0.o: No such file: No such file or directory
```

If I *add* -c to the CFLAGS, I get a compiled object called "main.obj -c" (there's a space between obj and -c there).

Does anyone have any idea what's happening? Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project uses the POSIX platform to enforce progarm and object file extensions, however the POSIX platform in SCons defines a function "escape":

```
def escape(arg):
    "escape shell special characters"
    slash = '\\'
    special = '"$()'

    arg = string.replace(arg, slash, slash+slash)
    for c in special:
        arg = string.replace(arg, c, slash+c)

    return '"' + arg + '"'
```

When it escapes the backslashes, it wreaks havoc in the Windows environment. Changing to a neutral platform, and specifying the extensions explicitly, fixes the problem.